# Why can't I save an object in Django?

Tags: python, django, frameworks

```
thechan = Score.objects.filter(content=44)[0:1]
thechan[0].custom_score = 2
thechan[0].save()
```

I do print statements, and it shows everything fine. However, it's not SAVING!

I go into my database, and I run a simple SELECT statement..and it's not changed!

```
select custom_score FROM music_score where content_id = 44;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What's going on here is that Score.objects.filter() doesn't return a regular list, but a [QuerySet](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/).  QuerySets behave like lists in some ways, but every time you slice one you get a new QuerySet instance, and everytime you index into one, you get a new instance of your model class.

That means your original code does something like:

```
thechan = Score.objects.filter(content=44)[0:1]
thechan[0].custom_score = 2

thechan = Score.objects.filter(content=44)[0:1]
thechan[0].save() # saves an unmodified object back to the DB, no effective change
```

If for whatever reason you needed to do this on a QuerySet rather than just using get(), you could write:

```
thechan = Score.objects.filter(content=44)[0]
thechan.custom_score = 2
thechan.save()
```

instead.  This distinction becomes a bit more important if you are, say, iterating over the elements of a QuerySet instead of dealing with a single record.

Answer (score -1):

Fixed.

```
thechan = Score.objects.get(content=44)
thechan.custom_score = 2
thechan.save()
```

Comment: 2 warnings: Django will raise for you: "MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Score" and, if more than 1 "content", will raise Object.DoesNotExist if no results.