# Why is save not working in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm using `manage.py shell` and run something like this:

```
d=Document.objects.get(pk=1)
d.scores  
{1:0,2:0,3:0}  
d.scores[1]=5
d.scores
{1:5,2:0,3:0} 
d.save()
```

But viewing `d` in the database reveals that it hasn't been updated. What am I doing wrong?? I checked out what's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528656/why-cant-i-save-an-object-in-django), but `d` is definitely a `Document` instance.

If it helps, **models.py** looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Document(models.Model):
    fileName=models.CharField(max_length=200)    
    fileUrl=models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    scores={1:0,2:0,3:0}
```

Comment: Show us your model definition please, especially what `scores` is supposed to be!

Comment: What does your actual SQL table structure look like, based on this model definition? Is there really a scores column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your 'scores' class variable isn't an instance of any of Django's *Field classes. I would imagine the 'scores' field isn't even on the table in the DB, since the field classes are what defines all of that, and what gets saved to the DB, among other things.